# how to get the array values in jsp

Tags: java, javascript, arrays, jsp, servlet-3.0

When I execute this only the last value in array returned as output when I use `request.getParameter("quantity")` in my JSP file. How can I pass the entire array with all of its values to the JSP file?

**myfile1.js:**

```
function savetheChanges()
{
    for(var i=0;i<16;i++)
    {
        quants[i]=document.getElementById("quantity"+i).value;
        kot1[i]=document.getElementById("kot"+i).value;
        itemcode1[i]=document.getElementById("itemcode"+i).value;
        var billno=document.getElementById("billno").value; 
        document.detailsview.action ="BillCB.jsp?method=" + "17" + "&billno=" +billno+ "&itemcode=" +itemcode[i]+ "&kot=" +kot1[i]+ "&quantity="+quants[i];
     }
}
```

**myfile2.jsp:**

(While getting the values I get only the first two elements of array)

```
billdetails_be.billno = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("billno"));
String[] quantCB = request.getParameterValues("quantity");
String[] kotCB = request.getParameterValues("kot");
String[] itemCB = request.getParameterValues("itemcode");
int[] quantarr = new int[quantCB.length];
int[] kotarr = new int[kotCB.length];
int[] itemarr = new int[itemCB.length];
System.out.println("beforeloop " + itemarr.length);
for (int i = 1; i < quantarr.length; i++) {
  quantarr[i] = Integer.parseInt(quantCB[i]);
}
for (int i = 1; i < kotarr.length; i++) {
  kotarr[i] = Integer.parseInt(kotCB[i]);
}
for (int i = 1; i < itemarr.length; i++) {
  itemarr[i] = Integer.parseInt(itemCB[i]);
}
for (int i = 1; i < itemarr.length; i++) {
  int quantint = quantarr[i];
  int kotint = kotarr[i];
  int itemint = itemarr[i];
  System.out.println("value in array:" + (quantarr[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function savetheChanges()
{
    var quantity = new array[];
    for(var i=0;i<16;i++)
    {
        quantity[i]=document.getElementById("quantity"+i).value;
     }
     document.detailsview.action ="BillCB.jsp?method=" + "17" + "&billno=" +billno+ "&quantity="+quantity;
}
```

pass array in Query String once and then

use `request.getParameterValues("quantity")` it will give you array

for example

```
<%

String[] favouriteCars = request.getParameterValues("favouritecar");
   for (int i = 0; i < favouriteCars .length; i++) {
      String car = favouriteCars [i];
      System.out.println("car name::"+car);

%>
```

above code will get all cars and print it on jsp or you can also use `JSTL` to itrate your array on jsp

Comment: Its showing error as,"The method getParameterNames() in the type ServletRequest is not applicable for the arguments (String)"

Comment: yeah i have tried that Mr.Nirav .but i need to allocate that to a integer value which is accessed using object.(i.e.,billdetails_be.quantity=Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("quantity"));

Comment: @VigneSh :: then use Integer.parseInt("value");

Comment: As you said,i have tried that too.its not working Nirav. Is it better to covert the array values into object?if so, provide me the steps if possible.thanks!

Comment: @VigneSh:: it works for me but first of all you have to clear with your doubts and try it to convert in int rather than Object

Comment: @VigneSh try yourself and when you stuck at any point i will help you buddy :)

Comment: I followed the steps said by you.but i could get only the first and last elements of the array.